# Removing shapes on a mouse click - Angular 6

Tags: openlayers, angular

So I can remove a layer fine, and I can see how I can remove a feature(shape) by grabbing it's id lets say and populating the list of current features for the user to select.

But ideally I want to be able to select a remove button and then click on the feature(shape) that I'd like to remove.

I see that there are a couple of remove properties at my disposal one on the Shape object and one on the Modify object but can't seem to work out how to use them on a click event.

Edit ***

With the help of Mike the function at the moment looks like this

```
  removeShape(){
var layer = this.vectorLayer;
this.coreMap.map.removeInteraction(this.draw);
this.coreMap.map.removeInteraction(this.snap);
this.coreMap.map.on('click', function(evt: any) {
  this.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function(feature) {
      layer.getSource().removeFeature(feature);
      return true;
    });
});
  }
```

I can console log the feature absolutely fine as well so it's selecting it, but despite passing it into removeFeature nothing appears to be happening.

Comment: What does console log show for `layer` in the callback?  Using `var source = this.vectorSource;`  and  `source.removeFeature(feature);` should have the same effect. The code definitely works in plain OpenLayers, there may be a problem with scope due to Angular so you should tag you question Angular.

Comment: It returns an _ol_layer_Vector_ object, and I forgot to mention that the function does actually throw an error of Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined.

Comment: ol_feature obj even sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something as simple as this would do it.  It returns true after the first feature, so won't remove more than one if they overlap.  You might want to add further checks.

```
  map.on('click', function(evt) {
    this.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
      function(feature, layer) {
        layer.getSource().removeFeature(feature);
        return true;
      });
  });
```

You could also try keeping the original context for `this` in the callback

```
this.coreMap.map.on('click', function(evt: any) {
  this.coreMap.map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
    function(feature) {
      this.vectorSource.removeFeature(feature);
      return true;
    });
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: The forEachFeatureAtPixel is throwing an error Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, any clue as to what the issue might be there my friend?

Comment: It should work just by adding the code after setting up the map.  If you are using Angular you would replace `map` with whatever you are using as the map object (based on your previous question `this.coreMap.map`)

Comment: I'm assuming that I'm going to need to pass in some form of event object into the function to fulfil the undefined error? So it has access to the x & y coords?

Comment: `this` inside the callback will be the map

Comment: Can't seem to read the layer.getSource returns null, tried to assign the layer variable to my vectorLayer field outside the function but no luck there either returning cannot read prop of forEach undefined

Comment: It may be because the layers are not managed by the map, see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel .  In your previous qyestion you are using a layer manager (is that an Angular add-on?) `this.coreMap.layerManager.addLayer` instead of OpenLayers  `this.coreMap.map.addLayer`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87924/discussion-between-munerz-and-mike).

Comment: Updated the post to reflect what the function currently looks like.